# framework7-react integration in project

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

is it possible to integrate framework7-react (one component) into a ready-made react project? can I use it only as a UI framework, like react-bootstrap?
Or you need to create a project from scratch using framework7-react with its routing, etc.

I'm trying to deploy the project, but I get constant errors, I want to understand if it makes sense to understand it, because I only need a few components because of their UI

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.